# Argparse: expected one argument

Tags: python, argparse

I have argparse arguments setup in the following fashion:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='foobar')
parser.add_argument('url', metavar='URL')
parser.add_argument('-k', dest='kindle_type', default='kindle3')
parser.add_argument('-n', dest='gallery_name', default='Gallery')
parser.add_argument('-d', dest='dropbox_dir')
args = parser.parse_args()

print parser.parse_args(['imgur_url', '-k'])
```

However, when I run `script.py -k kindledx http://url.com`, I get the following 
error: `gallery2kindle.py: error: argument -k: expected one argument`

Wasn't an argument called when I used 'kindledx' after flag '-k'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Wasn't an argument called when I used 'kindledx' after flag '-k'?

It was, and if you add a `print args` after `args = parser.parse_args()`, you can see the parsing works:

```
~/coding$ python ap.py -k kindledx http://url.com
Namespace(dropbox_dir=None, gallery_name='Gallery', kindle_type='kindledx', url='http://url.com')
```

but in this line

```
print parser.parse_args(['imgur_url', '-k'])
```

you *don't* pass an argument to k.  Compare

```
print parser.parse_args(['imgur_url', '-k', 'kindledx'])
```

which produces

```
Namespace(dropbox_dir=None, gallery_name='Gallery', kindle_type='kindledx', url='imgur_url')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the first result of googling this error, I want to share that it can happen if you follow advice to compatible with Windows `/` in Linux:

```
arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prefix_chars='-+/', description='desc')
```

This causes `-option /path/path` throws `expected one argument` even though it looks like valid. You need quotes it to be `-option '/path/path'` or remove the `/` in the `prefix_chars` above to fix it.